# Inactive link in slider button

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, slider

"SAIBA MAIS" button should point to a link, but when it points and clicks the button with the mouse, it does not work.

Correction has already been attempted in the slider settings panel. No effect.

Can it be corrected via code (CSS, HTML, PHP, etc.)?

[View button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l9cIy.jpg)

MAIN CODE LINES:

```html
<!-- LAYER NR. 7 -->
  <a class="tp-caption rev-btn " 
 href="https://up2place.com.br/vitacheckout/agende-seu-checkup/" target="_self"    id="slide-6-layer-6" 
    data-x="['left','left','left','left']" data-hoffset="['32','26','306','138']" 
    data-y="['top','top','top','top']" data-voffset="['518','488','473','225']" 
      data-width="157"
   data-height="none"
   data-whitespace="nowrap"
 
   data-type="button" 
   data-actions=''
   data-responsive_offset="on" 
   data-responsive="off"
   data-frames='[{"delay":9.8956298828125,"speed":300,"frame":"0","from":"opacity:0;","to":"o:1;","ease":"Power3.easeInOut"},{"delay":"wait","speed":300,"frame":"999","to":"opacity:0;","ease":"Power3.easeInOut"},{"frame":"hover","speed":"0","ease":"Linear.easeNone","to":"o:1;rX:0;rY:0;rZ:0;z:0;","style":"c:rgb(242,121,29);bg:rgba(255,255,255,1);bs:solid;bw:0 0 0 0;"}]'
   data-textAlign="['inherit','inherit','inherit','inherit']"
   data-paddingtop="[12,12,12,12]"
   data-paddingright="[35,35,35,35]"
   data-paddingbottom="[12,12,12,12]"
   data-paddingleft="[35,35,35,35]"

   style="z-index: 7; min-width: 157px; max-width: 157px; white-space: nowrap; font-size: 17px; line-height: 17px; font-weight: 500; color: rgba(255,255,255,1); letter-spacing: px;font-family:Roboto;background-color:rgb(236,157,54);border-color:rgba(0,0,0,1);outline:none;box-shadow:none;box-sizing:border-box;-moz-box-sizing:border-box;-webkit-box-sizing:border-box;cursor:pointer;text-decoration: none;">SAIBA MAIS </a>
 </li>
</ul>
<div style="overflow:hidden;width:100%;height:100%;top:0px;left:0px;" class="tp-static-layers">

  <!-- LAYER NR. 8 -->
```

CODE SOURCE OF THE PAGE IN: https://up2place.com.br/vitacheckout/

Comment: `.tp-static-layers` has a higher z-index than the button, so it is appearing in front of the button, rendering it unclickable. I tested that class with no z-index and the link worked fine.

Comment: Correct! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You have visible `div.tp-static-layers` that lie over layer with button.